# Data binding in JsViews

Tags: javascript, template-engine, jsrender, jsviews

I have an array of strings and an object whose properties are derived from this array. For example,

```
var arrayOne = ["One","Two", "Three"];
var objOne = {};

for(var i=0;i<arrayOne.length;i++){
    objOne[arrayOne[i]] = "some val";
    objOne[arrayOne[i]+"index"]=i;
}
```

I would like to bind this in the template dynamically like

```
{^{for arrayOne}}
<input data-link="objOne[:#data]" type="text"/>
{{/for}}
```

I tried the above approach and a few variations of the same without any luck.Can this be accomplished or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better not to iterate through the `arrayOne` array, but instead iterate directly the properties of `objOne`, along the lines of:

```
{^{props objOne}}
  {{if key.slice(-5) !== "index"}}
    <input data-link="prop" type="text"/>
  {{/if}}
{{/props}}
```

See http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvpropstag.

Comment: I wanted to generate dynamic selection lists and props property with conditions worked just fine. Thanks..